# argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

this is mi query

```
with r as (
 select id, created_at from table1 ta 
)
select * from r 
union all 
select id, created_at  from table2 tb where confirmed_at IS null ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
and not exists (
select * from r
)
```

and the response is
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
Position: 203

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: That's a PostgreSQL error, not a MySQL error. I've changed your tags to match.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you have your `order by` clause in the middle of your `where` clause, instead of after it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to return records from the second half of the union only in the case where the where the first half be empty.  Here is one way:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT id, created_at FROM table1
)

SELECT id, created_at FROM r
UNION ALL
SELECT id, created_at
FROM table2
WHERE confirmed_at IS NULL AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r) = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: hi, yes i want do that, and return the last row
but returns
ERROR: relation "r" does not exist

Comment: It looks like you are not running my entire answer.  Run the entire block of code, _including_ the CTE named `r`.  Then it should work.